# Ground state of hydrogen molecule using Heitler–London method (H-L)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, eigenvalue, hydrogen, variational-calculus

I am reading The Theory of Magnetism I, by Mattis. In Chapter 2, a hydrogen molecule is studied in the following way:

We have a Hamiltonian of a hydrogen molecule: 
$$H = H^0_1 + H^0_2  + H^\lambda \tag{1}$$

where:

$$ H^0_1 = \left ( \frac{p_1^2}{2m}-\frac{e^2}{r_{1a}} \right ), \quad H^0_2 = \left ( \frac{p_2^2}{2m}-\frac{e^2}{r_{2b}} \right ), \quad H^\lambda =\left(  \frac{e^2}{R_{ab}}+\frac{e^2}{r_{12}}-\frac{e^2}{r_{1b}}-\frac{e^2}{r_{2a}} \right )$$

where (a,b) represent the nuclei of each hydrogen atom and the numbers 1,2 refer to their respective electron.

The eigenfunctions of $H_a \equiv H_1^0$ and $H_b \equiv H_2^0$ are: $\phi_a(\vec{r_1})$ and $\phi_b(\vec{r_2})$ and we can define $\Psi_I = \phi_a(\vec{r_1}) \phi_b(\vec{r_2})$ and $\Psi_{II} = \phi_a(\vec{r_2}) \phi_b(\vec{r_1})$

Defining $U$, $V$ and $l$ as:

$$ l \equiv \int d^3 r \phi_a^*(\vec{r})\phi_b(\vec{r});  \quad U \equiv \int d^3r_1d^3r_2 \Psi_I^* \Psi_{II} H^\lambda \tag{2a}$$  $$V \equiv \int d^3r_1d^3r_2 |\Psi_{II}|^2 H^\lambda =  \int d^3r_1d^3r_2 |\Psi_{I}|^2 H^\lambda\tag{2b} $$

Then a variational function: $\Psi = c_I \Psi_I + c_{II} \Psi_{II}$ is chosen. And in order to determine the ground state (in terms of $c_I$ and $c_{II}$)we solve the following variational problem:

$$E_{var} = \frac{\int d^r_1 d^3r_2 \Psi^* H \Psi}{\int d^r_1 d^3r_2 \Psi^*  \Psi}, \quad \frac{\partial E_{var}}{\partial c_{I,II}} = 0 \tag{3}$$

Then he changes the variational problem to the following eigenvalue problem:

$$ \left ( \begin{matrix} V & U \\ U^\dagger& V  \end{matrix} \right ) \left ( \begin{matrix} c_I \\ c_{II}  \end{matrix} \right ) = (E-2E_0) \left ( \begin{matrix} 1 & l^2 \\ (l^2)^* & 1  \end{matrix} \right ) \left ( \begin{matrix} c_I \\ c_{II}  \end{matrix} \right )\tag{4} $$

Where he finds 2 solutions:

$$ c_I = \pm c_{II} \qquad E_{\pm} = 2 E_0 + \frac{V\pm U}{1\pm l^2}\tag{5}$$

My question is: How can $E_-$ and $E_+$ be both minimum values of $E_{var}$? If $(c_I,-c_I)$
 is the solution for $E_-$, then can't we change it slightly to get an energy $E = E_- +\delta E < E_+$?

Comment: You are not helping yourself by using an undefined uncommon acronym.  Someone who might be able to answer might not bother opening the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E_\pm$ are eigenvalues of Eq. (4) and stationary values of $E_{var}$. They are not minimum values.

Comment: What is exactly minimized in the variational principle, if it is not energy?

Comment: I understand the fact that it is looking for stationary values. But how does equation (3) is set to find stationary, and not minimal, values?